# Ignite configuration with absolute path

Tags: ignite

I downloaded Ignite 2.5.0 (I use maven dependences in Eclipse on a Mac for my Java class), and I tried to start Ignite with a configuration file given with an absolute path:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("/Users/ahajnal/Documents/git/ignite/target/classes/default-config.xml")) {}
}
```

but I got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to find configuration in: file:/Users/ahajnal/Documents/git/ignite/target/classes/default-config.xml
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:990)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:355)
at hu.sztaki.lpds.ml.ignite.WekaIgnite.main(WekaIgnite.java:82)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find configuration in: file:/Users/ahajnal/Documents/git/ignite/target/classes/default-config.xml
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:116)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:744)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:945)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
... 1 more
```

The config file is there:

```
$ cat /Users/ahajnal/Documents/git/ignite/target/classes/default-config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...
```

and:

```
new File("/Users/ahajnal/Documents/git/ignite/target/classes/default-config.xml").exists() is true
```

According to docs this path can be absolute.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the problem is that *default-config.xml* file has only abstract `IgniteConfiguration`. This is the case in the default configuration file in examples.

Check, if the configuration bean's definition has `abstract=true` parameter, and remove it if it does.

**P.S.**
Creating `Ignite` as a resource of a `try` block is a pretty bad idea, since the node will stop right after execution of the `try` block is finished.

Comment: Denis, you got it, removing abstract=true solved it. Thank you!